# Rails 6 app not deploying to Heroku - Unknown Syntax Error: Unsupported option name ("--no-progress")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Rails 6 app to Heroku and am running into this error:

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Unknown Syntax Error: Unsupported option name ("--no-progress").
remote:        
remote:        $ yarn install [--json] [--immutable] [--immutable-cache] [--check-cache] [--inline-builds] [--mode #0]
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

From googling around I think this might be something to do with yarn. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with running the `yarn install` command. Are you specifying a specific version of `yarn`?

Comment: "yarn": ">=1.0.0" This is the only thing I see in my package.json. When I run yarn -v the result is 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I had installed yarn version 3.1.1. I was getting this error in the Terminal when I tried to precompile the production assets for my Rails 5.2 application. I downgraded the yarn version to 1.22.17 and successfully precompiled my assets without the error.

Here are the terminal commands and messages.

```
[railsappfolder] (master) rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
Unknown Syntax Error: Unsupported option name ("--no-progress").

$ yarn install [--json] [--immutable] [--immutable-cache] [--check-cache] [--inline-builds] [--mode #0]
[railsappfolder] (master) yarn set version 1.22.17
➤ YN0000: Retrieving https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v1.22.17/yarn-1.22.17.js
➤ YN0000: Saving the new release in .yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.17.cjs
➤ YN0000: Done in 1s 665ms
[railsappfolder] (master) rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
yarn install v1.22.17
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
✨  Done in 0.05s.
```